# Is there a better way to assign a data type to a field?

Tags: f#

I have a variable declared like this:

```
type Variable = {
    name : string
    id : int
    datatype : Object
}
```

Later on, I would like to do something like this:

```
match variable.datatype with
| :? System.Byte -> printf "Byte"
| :? System.Double -> printf "Double"
| _ -> printf -> "Other type"
```

My initial attempt was to declare `variable` like so **(A)**:

`let variable = { name = "foo"; id = 0; datatype = System.Byte }`

However, this results in `datatype` containing something like `<fun:variable@31>`, and the `match` doesn't behave as desired - it always hits the "other" case.

I found a workaround, namely 
`let variable = { name = "foo"; id = 0; datatype = Unchecked.defaultof<Byte> }`. However, this doesn't express the intention as clearly.

How can I improve the declaration of `Variable` to have `datatype` contain a `Type`, so that the declaration in **(A)** works?

I'm trying to learn F# and .NET, there is no production code or homework involved here. So there aren't any constraints apart from having the desired `match` behavior on basic value types and possibly `string` as well. It is obvious that I'm missing some basic knowledge (vocabulary relating to language features, etc) that could solve this problem quite easily, but I've hit a roadblock trying to figure out what that might be.

Comment: Use `System.Type`, not `System.Object`

Comment: short answer is you cannot, the Type belongs to the field, the contents of the field have to contain a value that is the specificed type. However judging from the question, you could just assign a string, that says `System.Byte`. What you did, is basically assigned the `null` value for `Systyem.Byte` with `Unchecked.defaultof`. It's basically the empty value for the type. So maybe that is what you want.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I did also try that. The declaration in **(A)** then resulted in error `This function takes too many arguments, or is used in a context where a function is not expected`. What am I missing?

Comment: if you change your `print` function to:`let print variable =
    match variable.datatype with
    | x when x = typeof<System.Byte> -> 
        printfn "Byte"
    | x when x = typeof<System.Double> -> 
        printfn "Double"
    | _ -> printfn "Other type"` Is it okay for you?

Comment: broken formatting, really better chatting in [chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)

Answer (score 3):

One solution is to create a simple wrapper type for `datatype`:

```
type DataType =
| Byte
| Char
| Int
| Double
| String
```

(Aside: It looks odd to reuse language keywords in this way.)

The declaration for `Variable` then becomes:

```
type Variable = {
    name : string
    id : int
    datatype : DataType
}
```

Declare `variable` in the way we wanted: `let variable = { name = "foo"; id = 0; datatype = Byte }`.

Then writing the `match` statement in this way does the job:

```
match variable.datatype with
| Byte -> printf "Byte"
| Double -> printf "Double"
| _ -> printf "Other type"
```

Answer (score 1):

I think I have one half of an answer. As [Fyodor Soikin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/180286/fyodor-soikin) mentioned, we can use System.Type instead of System.Object.

```
type Variable = {
    name : string
    id : int
    datatype : System.Type
}

let variable = { name = "foo"; id = 0; datatype = typeof<System.Byte> }

let (|IsType|_|) (vartype: System.Type) (variable: Variable) =
    if variable.datatype = vartype then Some () else None

let ByteType = typeof<System.Byte> // why do I need these let-bindings
let DoubleType = typeof<System.Double> // ahead of the match construct ?

match variable with
| IsType ByteType -> printf "Byte"
| IsType DoubleType -> printf "Double"
| _ -> printf "Other type"
```

Edit: I am still not sure how to write the pattern matching. In particular, I can't figure out why I am not allowed to put `typeof<System.Byte>` directly in the match part of the code.